# Running out of processes (Flooded with sleep)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, freeze

We have a server running that has 2 connections to the database, they are both created using a pool.

**Example:**

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: config.mysql.host,
  user: config.mysql.user,
  password: config.mysql.pass,
  database: config.mysql.database
});
```

However, there's a lot of queries we do but a pool takes care of handling/closing active connections I was told.

Now connections are just piling up and old connections are not being taken care of. Eventually we will run out of available connections and the server will go hanging.

**Query function;**

```
var query = function(query){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    con.query(query, function(err, row){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }

      resolve(row);
    });
  });
}
```

**Usage of function;**

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `isBanned` = 0').then(function(users){
  //active users
}).catch(function(err){
  ...
});
```

All connections that are being piled up are in command **Sleep**

Edit: merged the connections into one database pool

**Main.js**

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 250,
    host: config.mysql.host,
    user: config.mysql.user,
    password: config.mysql.pass,
    database: config.mysql.database,
    charset: 'utf8_general_ci'
});
module.exports.pool = pool;
```

**Database.js** (pretty much just for the query function)

```
var main = require('./server.js');

var query = function(query){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    main.pool.query(query, function(err, row){
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }

      resolve(row);
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  con: main.pool,
  query: query
};
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184652/discussion-on-question-by-borda-running-out-of-processes-flooded-with-sleep).